# What is the inverse function of $f(x)=x-\log x (0<x<1)$

Tags: calculus

What is the inverse function of $f(x)=x-\log(x)$ where $0<x<1$?

Comment: Is $f$ a real valued function?

Answer (score 1):

By solving the equation $y=x-\log x$ in $(0,1)$, we get $x= -W\left(-e^{-y}\right)$, where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). You can verify this result by definition.